# why this webmethod doesn't gets called by $.ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

This is the method

```
 [WebMethod]
   public static string[] GetCustCodeFromCustomerName(string[] custName)
   {
       if (custName.Length == 0)
           return null;
       else
       {
           List<string> items = new List<string>();
           StringBuilder custList = new StringBuilder();
           string custListstr = string.Empty;
           for (int i = 0; i < custName.Length; i++)
               custList.Append(custName.ElementAt(i) + ", ");
           custListstr = custList.ToString().Substring(0, custList.Length - 2);
           try
           {
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
               SqlDataReader sdr;
               DataSet ds;
               cmd.CommandText = "sp_sel_custcodeFromCustName";
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customercodeinlist", custListstr);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchId", Globals.BranchID);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Flag", 1);
               sdr = AppClass.ExecuteReader(cmd);
               ds = AppClass.GetData(cmd);
               while (sdr.Read())
               {
                   items.Add("" + sdr.GetValue(0));
               }
               sdr.Close();
               sdr.Dispose();
               return items.ToArray();
           }
           catch (Exception)
           {
               return null;
           }
       }
   }
```

I am calling it like this...

```
custList = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function () { return    $(this).closest('tr').find('.grdCustName').text() }).get();

         $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "~/AutoComplete.asmx/GetCustCodeFromCustomerName",
                data: "{custName:'" + custList + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("success" + result);
                }
            });
```

I've tried various combinations, without `contentType` and `datatype`, with `get` instead of post, but still nothings seems to work so far. Can anyone help?

Comment: why are you putting a `~` in the url?

Comment: @davids: It represents the web root, but it only works in server side code.

Comment: @davids
its to indicate the root

Comment: Yes, but I think it doesn't make sense here. As far as I am concerned, you can supply a path or a complete url in the `url` property of the `ajax` method. In case it is a path, it will be concatenated to the current domain. Correct me if I'm wrong please!! :)

Comment: What framework version you've? Try to create another service method and request it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have to remove `~` operator and I *think* there is something wrong with Webservice code and json parameter.

Have a look at sample (both .aspx and .asmx are under the root of webapp):

**sample.aspx**

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#button1").click(function () {
            /* data parameter - array */
            var param = "{'custName': ['aa','bb','cc']}";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SampleWs.asmx/GetList",
                data: param,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert(data.d);
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**SampleWs.cs**

---

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://localhost/jquery/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class SampleWs : System.Web.Services.WebService {
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public   string[] GetList(string []custName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < custName.Length; i++)
            custName[i] = custName[i].ToUpper();
        return custName;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a call to `.get()` with no arguments at the end of this line:

```
custList = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function () { return    $(this).closest('tr').find('.grdCustName').text() }).get();
```

You may consider removing it.

Also as others have mentioned you should remove the `~` character from the URL as that only works on server-side code.

Comment: I removed the last `.get()` call. Also, changed the `~\` to `..\`. But still nothing

Comment: Is the server returning any kind of response at all (check with firebug with "Show XMLHttpRequests" turned on. If not, then the server it returning NULL. Also, your `$.ajax` call is expecting JSON but your server may not be returning (properly formatted?) JSON.